# What Software Is Available To Search A Windows Network

Tags: windows, networking

I am trying to find a software application / suite that will allow me to search a Windows 2003 based network (both server's and attached nodes). The goals being:

- It should be fast and non-invasive to
  a node being scanned (from a
  performance stand point)
- It should allow for a targeted scan
  (i.e. search for file *.pst).
- It should be able to scan multiple
  Windows operating system versions
  (Vista, Win7, XP, anything older is
  not needed).

I have found a few packages out there but there none that I have seen so far meet all three goals from my experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Microsoft Search Server 2008 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/enterprisesearch/en/us/search-server-express.aspx#first-tab).  It's free (as in free beer) and should run on your network fine.

Comment: According to the system requirements it requires Windows® SharePoint® Services 3.0 which is not available on the network in question. Do you possibly have re-world experience with this product?

Comment: As far as I know, Share Point Services are free to download here:  http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/product/related-technologies/Pages/windows-sharepoint-services.aspx.  I don't have any real-world experience with this product yet, but I'll be looking at it next week.

Answer (score 1):

Everything http://www.voidtools.com/

Comment: Yes I've seen this already but per their FAQ it only search local / removable drives.

Comment: The FAQ indicates it only search local or removable volumes.